# How to open the Amazon AppStore directly from my Android application?

Tags: android, updates, amazon-appstore

I have seen answers regarding Amazon Appstore from iPhone but not from Android. I'm trying to make a button that will open the Amazon Appstore (for android) on my app's page.

Here is how it's done for Google Play:

```
final String appPackageName = context.getPackageName();

try {
    activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)); 
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName));
}
```

How should I replace the Strings so that it works "the same" for the Amazon AppStore?

Comment: You just want the package name of the Amazon app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch an application from another application on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/launch-an-application-from-another-application-on-android)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Amazon app store URI is

```
amzn://apps/android?
```

Directing to a particular app would look like

```
amzn://apps/android?p=com.amazon.mp3
```

Source: [Linking To the Amazon Appstore for Android](https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/community/post/Tx3A1TVL67TB24B/Linking-To-the-Amazon-Appstore-for-Android.html)

Comment: They seem to have removed this in their most recent release - it is not even handling web searches natively either. It must be a mistake...

Comment: The source link has been changed: [Link to Amazon from within Your App](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/reports-promo/deeplink-to-the-amazon-client.html)

Answer (score 1):

Look into WebViews. It does exactly what you want, you can open a page in your own app. Simply define a webview in the xml, and use the java to display the page.

**How to do it without webview:**

(From docs)

> By default, a WebView provides no browser-like widgets, does not
>   enable JavaScript and web page errors are ignored. If your goal is
>   only to display some HTML as a part of your UI, this is probably fine;
>   the user won't need to interact with the web page beyond reading it,
>   and the web page won't need to interact with the user. If you actually
>   want a full-blown web browser, then you probably want to invoke the
>   Browser application with a URL Intent rather than show it with a
>   WebView. For example:
>
> ```
> Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.example.com");
>  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
>  startActivity(intent);
> ```

**With webview:**

```
 webview.loadUrl("http://slashdot.org/");

 // OR, you can also load from an HTML string:
 String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
 webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);
```

Let me know if this works by commenting.

Comment: I would like to use the Intent option. Can you help me with the strings?

Comment: Take a look at the duplicate in the comment. OP wants to use intents and needs to know the URI string of the Amazon App Store application in Android

Comment: @UFCInsider Take a look at `cricket_007`'s answer to see what string you need to put. Then, use the syntax described in my answer to actually make it work

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh, okay. That wasn't too clear to me. Hopefully the OP can still use this answer with your answer to finish his/her task. I have upvoted your answer :)